# Replace value of application.properties from other properties file

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have below file application properties file in my Spring boot application.
**All properties file are in src/main/resources folder**
Spring boot version is 2.1.6

> application.properties  application-dev.properties 
>   application-tst.properties
>
> application.properties  app.name={app.name} app.common=Common val
>   application-dev.properties   app.name=My dev app
>   application-tst.properties    app.name=My tst app

Dev and tst are maven profile i have created

```
 <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <env>dev</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>tst</id>
            <properties>
                <env>tst</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

If i am building the project with dev profile ,i shouuld get the following in my application.properties

> 1)mvn -Pdev clean install
>
> application.properties app.name=My dev app app.common=Common val
>
> 2)mvn -Ptst clean install
>
> application.properties app.name=My tst app app.common=Common val

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Maven Profiles aren't Spring Profiles. You are mixing those up. Also you shouldn't be building seperate artifacts for different environments, build 1 artifact and propagate that to a different environment. Use Spring Profiles to load the correct config.

Comment: Ok thanks.So can you tell how can i use a single artifact ?

Comment: Just build it like you normally build an application and you can use `-Dspring.profiles.active` to specify which profiles are active when running the applicaiton.

Comment: ok so you mean i should only maintain application-dev.properties and application-uat.properties

Answer (score 1):

You can use the environment variable to set the active profile like this

`mvn install -Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

or

`mvn install -Dspring.profiles.active=tst`

Comment: i want to build using mvn -Pdev clean install

Comment: @OracleMonkey see this article which explains how to link spring-boot runtime profiles with maven build time profiles [here](http://dolszewski.com/spring/spring-boot-properties-per-maven-profile/)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the recommended way, but you can use `org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-resources-plugin` as below.

#### pom.xml

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/resources/application-${env}.properties</filter>
        </filters>
    </build>
```

#### application.properties

```
app.name=@app.name@
app.common=Common val
```

#### application-dev.properties

```
app.name=My dev app
```

#### application-tst.properties

```
app.name=My tst app
```

and then, `mvn -Pdev clean install` or `mvn -Ptst clean install`

Comment: then what is the recommended way

Comment: As M. Deinum said earlier, you can use ``-Dspring.profiles.active`` to specify which profiles are active when running the applicaiton.

Comment: ok so you mean i should only maintain application-dev.properties and application-tst.properties

Comment: We set properties which do not change depending on the environment in ``application.properties``.

And we set properties which change depending on the environment in ``application-{profile}.properties``. (ex. database setting, API KEY)